# Polymer: fail to select pseudo class :target

Tags: css, css-selectors, polymer

I am trying to create a Polymer application that displays nested tabs. CSS selection on pseudo class `:first-child` seems to be not enforced by Iceweasel 35.0 and Chromium 40.0.2214.91.  Besides, the same version of Chromium used to selects `:target` for a while but then suddenly stops working.

Can it be Polymer's issue or my code that goes wrong?

index.html follows:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <script src="bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents.js"></script>
        <link rel="import" href="bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
        <title>My Tabs</title>
        <style>
            body {
                font-size:62.5%;
                z-index: 0;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <polymer-element name="my-tabs" attributes="tabs" noscript>
            <template id="t">
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="tabs.css">
                <template bind="{{tabs}}">
                    <article class="tabs">
                        <template repeat>
                            <section id="tab{{id}}">
                                <h2><a href="#tab{{id}}">{{TabTitle}}</a></h2>
                                <template if="{{!children}}">
                                    {{TabContent}}
                                </template>
                                <template ref="t" bind="{{children as tabs}}"></template>
                            </section>
                        </template>
                    </article>
                </template>
            </template>
        </polymer-element>
        <my-tabs></my-tabs>
    </body>
    <script>
        document.querySelector("my-tabs").tabs=
        [
            {
                TabTitle:"Tab 1"
                ,id:1
                ,children:[
                    {
                        TabTitle:"Tab 11"
                        ,id:11
                        ,TabContent:"Content 11"
                    }
                    ,{
                        TabTitle:"Tab 12"
                        ,id:12
                        ,TabContent:"Content 12"
                    }
                ]
            }
            ,{
                TabTitle:"Tab 2"
                ,id:2
                ,TabContent:"Content 2"
            }
            ,{
                TabTitle:"Tab 3"
                ,id:3
                ,children:[
                    {
                        TabTitle:"Tab 31"
                        ,id:31
                        ,TabContent:"Content 31"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ];
    </script>
</html>
```

tabs.css follows:

```
article.tabs
{
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 20em;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

article.tabs section
{
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    top: 1.8em;
    left: 0;
    bottom:0;
    right:0;
    background-color: #ddd;
    box-shadow: 0 3px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    z-index: 0;
}

article.tabs section:first-child
{
    z-index: 1;
}

article.tabs section h2
{
    position: absolute;
    font-size: 1.4em;
    width: 120px;
    height: 1.8em;
    top: -1.8em;
    left: 10px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    color: #999;
    background-color: #ddd;
}

article.tabs section:nth-child(2) h2
{
    left: 132px;
}

article.tabs section:nth-child(3) h2
{
    left: 254px;
}

article.tabs section:nth-child(4) h2
{
    left: 386px;
}

article.tabs section h2 a
{
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    line-height: 1.8em;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: inherit;
    outline: 0 none;
}

article.tabs section:target,
article.tabs section:target h2
{
    color: #333;
    background-color: #fff;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

The following screen shot shows that `z-index` of all tabs are `0` when page becomes ready. As a result, `Tab 3` is displayed instead of `Tab 1`.

[image: Incorrect screenshot]

The following screen shot shows that pseudo class selection `:first-child` is successfully applied to `Tab 1`. As a result, `z-index` associated with `Tab 1` is `1` after page load and hence `Tab 1` is correctly displayed on top of other tabs as expected with this **pure** html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>CSS Tests</title>
        <style>
            body {
                font-size:62.5%;
                color: #333;
                background-color: #e5eaff;
                margin: 10px;
                z-index: 0;
            }
        </style>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="tabs.css">
    </head>
    <body>
            <article class="tabs">
                <section id="tab1">
                    <h2><a href="#tab1">Tab 1</a></h2>
                    <article class="tabs">
                        <section id="tab11">
                            <h2><a href="#tab11">Tab 11</a></h2>
                            Content 11
                        </section>
                        <section id="tab12">
                            <h2><a href="#tab12">Tab 12</a></h2>
                            Content 12
                        </section>
                    </article>
                </section>
                <section id="tab2">
                    <h2><a href="#tab2">Tab 2</a></h2>
                </section>
                <section id="tab3">
                    <h2><a href="#tab3">Tab 3</a></h2>
                    <article class="tabs">
                        <section id="tab31">
                            <h2><a href="#tab31">Tab 31</a></h2>
                            Content 31
                        </section>
                        <section id="tab32">
                            <h2><a href="#tab32">Tab 32</a></h2>
                            Content 32
                        </section>
                    </article>
                </section>
            </article>
    </body>
</html>
```

[image: index.html without using Polymer]

Comment: I'm not familiar with Polymer but it doesn't look like you haven't told the browser to fill in `my-tabs` with your template content yet. See this basic example using HTML5 `<template>` in action: http://jsfiddle.net/9whheff6/

Comment: @TylerH `Index.html` does tell browsers to fill in the custom element with the line `<my-tabs></my-tabs>` just prior to the line `</body>`.

Comment: I was referring to the JavaScript that is required to populate the template, but I checked out Polymer a bit and it seems to do the call I mentioned above for you. The `<my-tabs>` tags in your `body` don't tell the browser anything. The JavaScript (that you write, or in this case, that Polymer writes) tells the browser what to add to the markup and where to add it, and how many times.